# Facebook Unity SDK compile error on import package

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I tried to add the Facebook SDK to my existing Unity 5 project using the official guide here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas

After importing the Facebook SDK custom package into my project via:
Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package..

After importing the package, I get the following 3 compilation errors:

- Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs(166,67): error
  CS0117 `PlayerSettings' does not contain a definition for`
  bundleIdentifier'
- Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs(166,13): error
  CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
  `FacebookSettingsEditor.SelectableLabelField(UnityEngine.GUIContent,
  string)' has some invalid arguments
- Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs(166,13): error
  CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
  `string'

The versions used are:

- Facebook SDK for Unity Package 6.2.2
- Unity 5 Version 5.0.0f4

I also closed the project and reopened it by restarting Unity. The errors are still there.

What could be the cause of the compilation errors and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Unity SDK currently only Support upto Unity 4.6 for web builds.
See Note in this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads
Which platform are you using?